# Не работает .join()

Tags: javascript, node.js

Сразу говорю, я новичок в JS. Я делаю бота для Discord

```
async function exec(client, command) {
    const commandFiles = require('../main')
    console.log(commandFiles.join(", ")) //выводит: commandFiles.join is not a function
}
```

Выше - код функции, которая должна при команде !help выводить в консоль строку с командами.

```
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./bot-commands/`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
```

Так выглядит commandFiles

Если выводить просто commandFiles без метода join, то выводит [массив команд](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bLoz.png), которые находятся в отдельной папке

Comment: //выводит: commandFiles.join is not a function >  означает, что такого метода не существует. А у массива всегда существует  join. Вывод - join  пытается склеить не массив, а что-то другое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас на скриношоте не массив команд, а объект, в котором этот массив лежит с ключом commandFiles. Если вы хотите достать сразу сам массив, то поменяйте

```
const commandFiles = require('../main')
```

На

```
const {commandFiles} = require('../main')
```

Либо эту часть оставтье как есть, но тогда джойните массив, а не объект:

```
commandFiles.commandFiles.join(", ")
```